# Complex function curve fitting (Python)

Tags: python, math, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm currently trying to fit data to this function to exctract "e/lambda" :
[image: Formula]

To do so, I tried (for the first time) to fit the data using python and I rearranged a little the fit function :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np

# data

Io = np.array([0.3,0.5,1.4,2.9,3.8])
Is = np.array([2.7,2.7,2.7,2.7,2.7])
R = Io/Is

T = np.array([0.,50,70,80,85])
F = R/R[0]

plt.plot(T, F, 'ro', label="original data")

# curvefit
## a = np.exp(e/lambda)

def func(T, a):
    return a * (((np.exp ((np.cos(T)-1)/(np.cos(T)))) - \
                 (np.exp ((1-np.cos(T))/((np.cos(T))**2)))) \
                / ((np.exp ((np.cos(T)-1)/(np.cos(T)))) - \
                   (np.exp ((1-np.cos(T))/((np.cos(T)))))))

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, T, F, maxfev=100000)

t = np.linspace(0,85)
plt.plot(t, func(t, *popt), label="Fitted Curve")

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

However, I'm getting this message : "Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 100000"

This might be more a mathematical issue since I've tried succesfully this code with another function :

```
def func(T, a, b, c):
    return a + np.exp(b*T-c)
```

[image: Fit obtained]

Does anyone know if it is possible to fit this function using it's "true" form ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Have you tried increasing `maxfev`? Or is it necessary to keep it at 100k?

Comment: `curve_fit` works best when you give it a reasonable initial guess for the parameters (and some argue that the initial guess should be a *required* argument).  Use the argument `p0` to pass in the initial guess.  The default is 1, and that might be a really bad initial guess for your function.  If you can provide an initial guess that is at least the correct order of magnitude, you'll have a better chance of getting `curve_fit` to succeed.

Comment: @WBM : Yes I've tried to increase the maxfev, however it just compute for a longer time and still show : "RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = (the value I chose)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I've tried adding p0=2.311 (the value that I should obtain). Unfortunately, the Error is still the same... I will try to let it compute with the p0 and a considerable maxfev to see if this find a fit

Comment: how is func() an implementation of the function at the top?